# Is it possible to link a JComboBox to a SQL Server database

Tags: java, sql-server, text, hyperlink, jcombobox

I have Server database which is linked to my Java application which is trying to simulate a playlist (or library of songs), however I want to add a feature where the user can select a artists name from the jcombobox, and all their songs come up. I know how to do this manually, but the problem is I want the jcombobox to update if the user adds new songs into the database with new artists names. I would then have to add the new artists name in the list for the jcombobox manually through the code.

my sql server database has a ID which is an int and primary key, Artists which is text, name which is text, rating which is int and playcount which is int. not sure if anything else is valuable but all i want to do is make the jcombobox automatically update if a new artist is added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for you. What it does : 
1) Creates a combobox 
2) builds a model for combobox from items of type DemoModelItem (try commenting out overrided toString method) 
3) sets combobox model

```
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;  
import javax.swing.JComboBox;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;  

class DemoModelItem {  
public String objectName;  
public String objectType;  

public DemoModelItem(String objectName,String objectType){  
    this.objectName = objectName;  
    this.objectType = objectType;  
}  

public String toString(){  
    return objectType+"-"+objectName;  
}  
}  

public class ComboTest {  
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {  
    Connection conn = null;  
    //open connection   
    return conn;  
}  

public static DefaultComboBoxModel buildComboBoxModel() throws Exception {  
    DefaultComboBoxModel comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();  
    String SQL = "SELECT object_name, object_type from some_table";          
    Connection c = null;  
    try {  
        c = getConnection();  
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL);  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
        while(rs.next()){  
            comboBoxModel.addElement(new DemoModelItem(rs.getString("OBJECT_NAME"),rs.getString("OBJECT_TYPE")));  
        }  
        rs.close();  
        ps.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        throw e;  
    }finally{  
        try{c.close();}catch(Exception e){;}  
    }  
    return comboBoxModel;  
}  

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();  
    comboBox.setModel(buildComboBoxModel());  

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Combo Demo");  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);  
    frame.pack();  
    frame.setVisible(true);  
}  
}
```

here instead of using 
model.addElement() try using JcomboBox.addItem();